# Different low resolution images using CNN

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, computer-vision

I am trying to classify different categories of plant using convolutional neural network (CNN). Each category of plant has small set of images. Size of each image is 1000 x 1000. To increase the number of images we divide each into patches of different size (i.e. 500x500, 250x250, and 125x125) and then applied data augmentation method. 
We tried to check different resolutions by averaging 16x16, 32x32, and 64x64 pixels.

I have attached the two low resolution images left 64x64 pixels and right 16x16 pixels.

[image]
By reducing the resolution, the bigger patches (500x500) can still extract better features and have high performance as compare to small patches?

Comment: What is actually the question? Your last sentence ends with a questionmark, but I have no idea what is it that you are asking.